# Adding Script by Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an ajax script that downloads pulls data of the server, which contains some javascript code. The response is placed into the `innerHTML` of a target div. After that, the script scans through the div that contains the new html for any script tags.

This is the point where it starts to stop working. Initially, I tried to add each script to the head, which it did successfully, but didn't load any scripts referenced externally (i.e. src="test.js"), nor run any of the new code.

My next attempt was to run through each script item, then use `eval` on `script.text`, which successfully executed the script that was parsed, but still didn't load any externally referenced scripts.

Does anyone have any suggestions of what to try next?

Comment: Adding script tags to the head should work. I know I've done that before. Forgive me if this is patronising but are you sure the scripts have loaded before you try and call methods in them?

Comment: They aren't loading at all. I tried it with a bunch of dummy scripts (simply had the content `alert('test #')`) which would be called, works fine if added while the document is loading, but not if after its already loaded...

Comment: Try to capture the ajax response to an div NOT in the DOM (`document.createElement('div')`) and insert that to the target div using `document.appendChild()`.

Comment: @madr tried that to, but both had the same result. Is there any reason to use `document.createElement('div');...;document.appendChild()` over `document.getElementById('xyz').innerHTML`? Generally I use the former, but for quick bits, I do use the latter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I you use jQuery, you could use this call:

```
$.getScript("test.js", function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
   console.log(data); //data returned
});
```

You can find documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Or with Mootools:

```
Asset.javascript("test.js");
```

You can find documentation here: http://mootools.net/docs/more/Utilities/Assets

Comment: Sounds useful, but the site i'm using this on doesn't use any javascript frameworks, so it would be annoying to include something like jQuery for just one function, but i'm digging through its source to see how it works